# Looking for a better solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a variation of products that can be purchased in different colors based on the Purchasers desire.

My first dropdown is if they buy 1 product which is easy wont waste your time.

The second is purchasing 2 products.
Dropdown 1 has black / white / red / blue
Dropdown 2 has black / white / red / blue

The second tier is purchasing 3 products

Dropdown 1 has black / white / red / blue
Dropdown 2 has black / white / red / blue
Dropdown 3 has black / white / red / blue

Each variation has a different link so for example there are on the 3 products, 48 ways to purchase Black. BK / BK / Bk and so on.

What I am trying to do, is create a code that takes black white red or blue, and creates a link regardless of the color.

Here is a link based on a color Black / Black / Black = http://get.pressybutton.com/cart/653746441:1 
Unfortunatly the link characteristics are not based on the color options (or this would be far easier). What I want to be able to do is create a method that regardless of white black red, or red black white, or black red white, that is chosen, the link will always be black red white.

Pretty extensive right. Here is the code I have created.
HTML

```
   <form id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
        <select accesskey="E" class="style stylethree combine3" id="target"
        name="selected">
            <option value="black">
                Black
            </option>

            <option value="blue">
                Blue
            </option>

            <option value="red">
                Red
            </option>

            <option value="white">
                White
            </option>
        </select> <select accesskey="E" class="style stylefour combine4" id=
        "target" name="selected">
            <option value="black">
                Black
            </option>

            <option value="blue">
                Blue
            </option>

            <option value="red">
                Red
            </option>

            <option value="white">
                White
            </option>
        </select> <select accesskey="E" class="style stylefive combine5" id=
        "target" name="selected">
            <option value="black">
                Black
            </option>

            <option value="blue">
                Blue
            </option>

            <option value="red">
                Red
            </option>

            <option value="white">
                White
            </option>
        </select> <input class="select_pre_1" type="button" value=
        "Get (3) Pressy’s!">
    </form>
```

Jquery

```
var solidLink = "http://get.pressybutton.com/cart/";
var col_1a;
var col_2a;

var col_1b;
var col_2b;
var col_3b; 
$('.select_pre_1').click(function(){
    /*** BLACK BLACK ---- COLOR ***/
    if(col_1b == "black" && col_2b == "black" && col_3b == "black"){

        window.location.href = solidLink+"653746441:1"
    }
    if(col_1b == "black" && col_2b == "black" && col_3b == "red"){
        window.location.href = solidLink+"653746445:1"
    }
    if(col_1b == "black" && col_2b == "black" && col_3b == "white"){
        window.location.href = solidLink+"653746449:1"
    }   
    if(col_1b == "black" && col_2b == "black" && col_3b == "blue"){

        window.location.href = solidLink+"653746497:1"
    }
});
```

Final thought.

What I want to do, is create a `var` that combines the three chosen variables, then computes them, regardless of the formation it should spit grab the proper link. Here is my example.

```
var solidLink = "http://get.pressybutton.com/cart/";
var col_1a;
var col_2a;

var col_1b;
var col_2b;
var col_3b;
var combine_3 = col_1b+","+col_2b+","+col_3b; 
$('.select_pre_1').click(function(){
    if(combine_3 == "black"){
       window.location.href = solidLink+"653746441:1"
    }
    if(combine_3 == "black, white, black")/*** The variation shouldnt matter ***/{
       window.location.href = solidLink+"653746449:1"
    }
});
```

I think the method above would work. So regardless of the color, it would just check to see if it has all three of those var. Lastly I know this can be done with json... (which I am not the best with).  THank you!!! I hope I spelled this out for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

instead of this

```
$('.select_pre_1').click(function(){
    /*** BLACK BLACK ---- COLOR ***/
    if(col_1b == "black" && col_2b == "black" && col_3b == "black"){

        window.location.href = solidLink+"653746441:1"
    }
    if(col_1b == "black" && col_2b == "black" && col_3b == "red"){
        window.location.href = solidLink+"653746445:1"
    }
    if(col_1b == "black" && col_2b == "black" && col_3b == "white"){
        window.location.href = solidLink+"653746449:1"
    }   
    if(col_1b == "black" && col_2b == "black" && col_3b == "blue"){

        window.location.href = solidLink+"653746497:1"
    }
});
```

you should nest your if statements to make it cleaner and more to the point,  if `col_1b` and `col_2b` aren't black it doesn't matter what `col_3b` is

```
$('.select_pre_1').click(function(){
    /*** BLACK BLACK ---- COLOR ***/
    if(col_1b == "black" && col_2b == "black"){
        if (col_3b == "black"){
        window.location.href = solidLink+"653746441:1";
        } else if col_3b == "red"){
            window.location.href = solidLink+"653746445:1";
        } else if col_3b == "white"){
        window.location.href = solidLink+"653746449:1";
        } else if col_3b == "blue"){
        window.location.href = solidLink+"653746497:1";
        }
    }
});
```

and you were missing semi-colons as well.

Writing your code like this is nested another level but it is clear and to the point.

Another way to do this is to use a Case Statement instead of an if block on the inside.

Comment: Your method instead is ok, accept the colors can be all 3 not just the last one. I see what you mean. I think .push of the variables should work good. thanks for the input, but there should be a way to measure the variables without having to do it from all angles, example, blk blk blk, wh blk wh, blk wh wh, it shouldnt matter the variables position.

Comment: there is a way to group the options in the HTML so that you can't pick more than one,  ahhh my brain is shutting down for the night, I am getting half an idea.....